How to analyze common-emitter amplifier by reflecting base impedance to emitter?
In chapter 2 of Dr. Middlebrook's video series Technical Therapy for Analog Circuit Designers he gives 2 examples of how solving a CE amplifier by "doing the algebra on the circuit diagram" gives low entropy expressions compared to the brute force nodal equations. I need help understanding the second example.
The screenshots of the 2 examples are shown from page 16 and 17 of the chapter 2 lecture notes (currently available at Venable Instruments website).


The first example is clear to me: he finds the input current from the input impedance of the CE amplifier. The output is found by applying the current gain to the input current. What he calls "reflecting emitter impedance to base" is just finding the input impedance, in my understanding.
Now in the second example, he "reflects the base impedance to the emitter". What is he doing in the second example?

Update
Adding some information to explain my confusion.
In general, we describe a unilateral two-port network by the input impedance \$Z_{IN}\$, output impedance \$Z_O\$, and a dependent source (i.e. voltage gain, current gain, etc.) as shown below.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In the first example, the input impedance and dependent source are clear, and I can get the same expression for the input impedance by grounding the emitter and applying a test source at the base.
The second example is confusing because it does not look like a regular two-port with separate input impedance and dependent source. I got \$Z_{IN} = r_E + \frac{R_s \parallel R_B}{1 + \beta}\$ (though it is less clear if you include emitter degeneration), but why doesn't he draw it like the schematic below? Anyway, it may just come down to a lack of familiarity with the T model.

simulate this circuit

Didn't read the linked paper. But the dynamic resistance (either $r_e^{:'}$ or $r_\pi$) can be applied either at the emitter or the base. They both reflect the tangent slope at the quiescent point found on the non-linear the Shockley diode equation curve. Since the active mode base current is $\beta+1$ (or $\approx \beta$) different from the emitter current the slope is altered by that difference. You just don't get to do both viewpoints at once. You pick one for a purpose at hand.

David, is there something still missing from what's already been written here? Or a problem in reading what you've been offered that could use some added explanation? If so, you may wish to ask using a comment underneath the answers below. If, after some attempts with the authors of answers here you are still just not getting the communication you feel you need, you could add something to your question or just comment here. I might try a 3rd approach then. But I'd rather you resolve this with those who have already tried to help out.

@periblepsis I added some comments. Both answers describe the output impedance of a common-collector amplifier, but I don't understand 1) how this applies to finding the gain of a common-emitter amplifier like in the example, and 2) what is the relationship between example 1 (reflecting emitter resistance to base) and example 2. By "relationship", I mean what are the similarities and differences.

Thanks, DavidG25. I see that you've added comments to those providing answers. Hopefully, they will do what they may to help out. If the responses aren't adequate and if I can see a different approach that may help I may add something. But for now, they need some time to consider your thoughts. But sincere thanks. Hopefully, your question ends well for you. I'll +1 now.

As I have said earlier, this is a T-model and this is why it does not look like a regular two-port network. As for the RE in series with re and RB/(b+1). As I was trying to show RB/(b+1) is seen at the emitter side in series with re.  What about RE?  If we look at it from an input signal point of view we see that RE is indeed in series with re plus  RB/(beta+1).  In my answer, I was trying to show that RB is transformed into an emitter side.  And RE appears in parallel because in my example we are looking from the emitter follower output side into the transistor. Not CE amplifier.

It seems like the T-model is causing too much confusion for you. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518032/pi-model-of-common-collector/518561#518561

I updated my answer by adding another example.

He is doing the same thing. But this time he doing it from the emitter terminal point of view.
Thus, any resistance at the base will be seen at the emitter side as a \$\beta + 1\$ smaller resistance.
You can prove to yourself by finding the \$R_{OUT}\$ of an emitter follower.
Let us try to find the \$R_{OUT}\$ for the equivalent circuit:

I hope that you see that \$R_E\$ is in parallel with the resistance seen from the emitter terminal into the BJT.
And our test current is
$$I_X = I_B + \beta I_B + I_{RE}$$
But if we ignore \$R_E\$ resistance for a moment we can find the transistor resistance seen from the emitter looking into BJT.
$$I_X = I_B + \beta I_B = I_B(\beta +1)$$
Additional we know that \$I_B = \frac{V_X}{r_\pi + R_B}\$
we can write
$$I_X = I_B(\beta +1)= \frac{V_X}{r_\pi + R_B}(\beta +1) = \frac{V_X (\beta +1)}{r_\pi + R_B} $$
$$\frac{I_X}{V_X} =\frac{\beta +1}{r_\pi + R_B} $$
And finally
$$Z_{OUT} = \frac{V_X}{I_X} = \frac{r_\pi + R_B}{\beta +1}||R_E $$
and because
$$r_\pi = (\beta +1)r_e $$
we have
$$Z_{OUT} = \frac{R_B}{\beta +1}||r_e||R_E $$
And this should be no surprise. We all know that
\$I_B = \frac{I_E}{\beta +1}\$ is true.
So this is why \$ R_B\$ is seen at the emitter side as \$ \frac{R_B}{\beta +1} \$  a smaller resistance.
EDIT
We can also use a DC to see the effect of "resistance transformation/reflection"
The original circuit:

And we wanted to solve for \$I_E\$ current.
From KVL we have:
$$V_{IN} = I_B R_B + V_{BE} + I_E R_E$$
The relation between the base current and the emitter current in a transistor is \$I_B = \frac{I_E}{\beta + 1}\$, we plug this into our equation
$$V_{IN} = \frac{I_E}{\beta + 1} R_B + V_{BE} + I_E R_E$$
And solve for \$I_E\$:
$$I_E = \frac{V_{IN} - V_{BE}}{ \frac{R_B}{\beta + 1} + R_E}$$
Notice that now the \$R_B\$ resistor "appears" on the "emitter side" as \$\beta + 1\$ smaller resistance.
Therefore the equivalent circuit will look like this:

I hope that this appendix helps.

I understood your answer to say that both examples 1) find the base current using the input impedance and the input voltage, and 2) find the output by scaling the base current by the current gain and the collector resistor.
Is the difference that the first example finds the input impedance by grounding the emitter and applying a test at the base while the second example grounds the base and applies a test at the emitter?

Also, if they both find the base current using the input impedance and input voltage, why is there still a connection between the input and the output in the second example? I would expect some impedance between the input and ground, and then a separate, dependent source at the output, just like the first example.

In a second example, the author is using T-model instead of a pi. http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/The%20Hybrid%20Pi%20and%20T%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Isn't he using the T model in both examples because we only see $r_e$ rather than $r_{\pi}$?

No, in the first example, we have a pi model. Also notice that $r_\pi = (\beta +1)r_e $.

Simply put, what do we see when looking at the transistor from the emitter side in a common-base stage?
Conceptual circuit
The phenomenon we observe in this transistor stage is much more general; it is a concept. So let's explore it with a conceptual equivalent circuit.
Connected "collector"
Current source viewpoint: Looking from the emitter side (CB stage), we can see a resistor Rb through which current Ib flows and a dynamic current source with current β.Ib connected in parallel to it. The combination of the two elements behaves like a "resistor" with a virtually decreased resistance Rb/(β + 1) = 1000/101 = 9.9 Ω.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Dynamic resistor viewpoint: We can think of the dynamic current source as a dynamic resistor with resistance Rb/β. So looking from the emitter side, we see the equivalent resistance of two resistors in parallel - the high-resistance Rb and the beta times low-resistance Rb/β. This is actually the so discussed “re”.

simulate this circuit
Disconnected "collector"
If we disconnect the collector, the resistance seen by the emitter voltage source is determined only by Rb = 1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
Real circuit
Finally, let's s replace the "conceptual transistor" with real one.
Connected collector
With negative emitter voltage: We can ground the base and connect a negative voltage source in the emitter. There is no power supply because the negative emitter dource acts as such.

simulate this circuit
As you can see, the resistance re seen from the emitter side is only 1 Ω. We should explore it graphically because it is a small-signal quantity. re is almost zero in the working part of the transistor input characteristic.

With positive emitter voltage: Above I have just tried to simplify the circuit to stay focused on the main idea because if the emitter voltage was positive, it would require an even higher positive base voltage and, naturally, a positive power supply voltage. So my idea was that by dropping the emitter voltage below zero, there was no need for the other two voltages. But let's also check the standard configuration with positive sources.

simulate this circuit

As you can see the result is almost the same; so we can omit these voltage sources.
Disconnected collector

simulate this circuit
Let's see the re graph to compare it with this above (of Schematic 2.1.1). As we can see, it has some resistance in the working region.

Conclusions
In a common-collector and common-base stage, the low-resistance (Rb/β) output part of the circuit (transistor CE) can be considered as connected in parallel to the high-resistance (Rb) input part of the circuit (transistor BE). As a result, the resistance re seen when looking at the emitter, is even lower - re = Rb/(β + 1).
See also my answer.
Improvement
I also created an enhanced version of this answer in collaboration with artificial intelligence.

I understand the output impedance of CC amplifier, but how does this apply to the derivation of the CE gain as shown in the lecture notes?

@DavidG25, formulas are not my forte. To find the CE gain, I prefer to use the transconductance (gm) parameter: Ic = gm.Vin, Vout = Ic.Rc = gm.Vin.Rc, G = Vout/Vin = gm.Rc (small-signal parameters).

@LvW, won't you take a stance on my "re" story? We have discussed it so many times and now I simulated it...
