# How would I find the gain equation for this circuit?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

[image]

I can neglect the Early Effect for the BJT, and assume the capacitance is infinite.
Using the small-signal AC model, I calculated $$r_e = 25 \Omega$$.
My question is, how do I set up my equations/circuit model to find Vo/Vsig?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476659/kvl-equations-for-this-small-signal-model/476666#476666

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518032/pi-model-of-common-collector/518561#518561